# Xamarin Hot Reload 'Local Device' not shown

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, hot-reload

I'm trying to get hot reload working on an existing xamarin.forms project, so I can deploy to my iOS devices directly without a mac.

I got this feature to at least show the 'Local Device' selection on a new project, but I can't get it to show this selection in the existing project therefore I cannot setup the hot reload.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?
If it helps I also added the iOS project build properties.
[image: iOS Build Properties]

Comment: What's your development target in info.plist? Does it lower than the system version of your local device?

Comment: Deployment target is 10.0 and my local device (iPhone 5s) has an iOS version of 12.4.7

Comment: But shouldn't it nevertheless show the 'Local Device' option?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Visual-Studio and Xamarin.forms?

Comment: Oh that might be a problem.. We use Xamarin Forms version 4.5.0.728 and Visual Studio version 16.5.4 (Which should not be a problem as I got it working on a test project)

Comment: You can have a try with the latest version of Xamarin.forms and Visual-Studio.

Comment: I'm also having this issue - using VS 2022, "Hot Restart" is enabled in the options, but no "Local Device" menu item shown.  Did you ever get this resolved?